# My date check statement isn't working properly

Tags: php, date

I have a date checker that checks if a date is between 2 other dates, but it's not working properly.

```
$maxDate = date('d/m/Y');
$minDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-30 days"));
$date = $unit['date_recorded'];
```

`var_dump($date)` returns:

```
string(19) "2016-05-02 15:27:15"
```

Now I have the statement:

```
if ($date >= $minDate AND $date <= $maxDate) { // do something }
```

But it never triggers this statment, even if I try to transform the `$date` with `date("d/m/Y", $date)` or use `strtotime()` on `$date` or all variables.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just use `time()` and compare the seconds (unix time)

Comment: its not the same format, date('d/m/Y') and 2016-05-02 15:27:15

Comment: @Alon Eitan, I tried it but the `var_dump()` of the variables returns the same number: `int(1464638248)`, `int(1464638248)`, `int(1464638248)`. Is it correct?

Comment: @grasshopper, as stated, even if I use `$date = date("d/m/Y", $date)` it results the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem #1

Both dates must have the same format for the comparison to work.

### Problem #2

> If I try to transform the $date with `date("d/m/Y", $date)`

The reason why it's not working is because the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function accepts a time, not a string.

To make it work, you have to do

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date))
```

However, this was just a side problem. The reason why you cannot compare dates with the `d/m/Y` is because:

```
$minDate = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-30 days")); // 30/04/2016
$maxDate = date('d/m/Y'); // 30/05/2016
$date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($unit['date_recorded'])); // 02/05/2016
```

As you can see, `$date` starts with **02** which is less than the `$minDate`'s **30**. It's taking the day in consideration before the year, or the month. So it's never going inside your if-case.

### Solution #1 - Convert all dates to Y-m-d format

Declare the value of `$unit['date_recorded']` for testing purposes:

```
$unit['date_recorded'] = "2016-05-02 15:27:15";
```

Now that we have a value for the unit variable, here's how we proceed:

```
$minDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-30 days"));
$maxDate = date('Y-m-d');
$date = $unit['date_recorded'];

if($date >= $minDate && $date <= $maxDate)
    echo "Do something...";
```

### Solution #2 - Convert all dates to unix timestamp

```
$minDate = strtotime("-30 days");
$maxDate = time();
$date = strtotime($unit['date_recorded']);

if($date >= $minDate && $date <= $maxDate)
    echo "Do something...";
```

Comment: I guess that's the issue, the early transformation of the date and than trying to compare it with other date string. I've done your way, to compare before transfom the date and it worked. Thanks you so much, I've spent a long time on this!

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but here it goes:

```
$date = new DateTime("2016-05-02 15:27:15");
$maxDate = new DateTime();
$minDate = new DateTime($maxDate->format());
$minDate->modify('-30 day');
if ($date >= $minDate and $date <= $maxDate)
{ 
 //... 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are probably getting precedence problems in your if clause.

Try putting more parenthesis:
if (($date >= $minDate) && ($date <= $maxDate)) { ...

And check if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried that, didn't work. (BTW it wasn't me that marked as not usefull your answer).

Comment: No problem William, although my answer was not correct, I just wanted to share a solution for a problem I had in the past.